# Two visibly exact strings are considered different

Tags: python-3.x, equality, discord

With my bot, you are to enter two inputs, a `score` and a `username`. The problem here is with `username`. This is the code:

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description="Moderates the server")


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def rate(stuff, score, username):
    user_scores = open("userratings.txt", "r")
    ratings = []
    with user_scores:
        for line in user_scores:
            newline = line.split("#")
            if newline[1].endswith("\n"):
                newline[1] = newline[1][:-1]
            ratings.append(newline)
    for item in ratings:
        item[1] = item[1].split()
    for item in ratings:
        await bot.say(item[0] + "#" + item[1][0] + " " + username)
        if username == item[0] + "#" + item[1][0]:
            await bot.say("HI")
            break


bot.run("token")
```

I will not reveal the token of course for privacy reasons. The problem occurs with the `if` statement within the last `for` loop where I compare the inputted username to the list of usernames which is steadily generated one by one with `item[0] + "#" + item[1][0]`. I input in my own username (`@Anthony (Tony's Farm)#3370`) and the bot outputs the same string as well as seen here:

[image]

Similar to how you ping people here with `@username`, you ping other users with `@username#id_number` which is provided to you by the server. As you can see, my bot does not say "Hi" even though it is able to duplicate my username and id perfectly. As you can see after that, I copied and pasted the characters in white and it pinged me thus the two strings, the one made by the program and the one made by me, are the same.

So how come two visibly accurate strings come out as different even though when I copied the bot's output, it was considered as the same?

**EDIT:** I have attempted debugging and it doesn't help:

[image]

Comment: Have you compared the strings character-by-character? Because if Python says they are not equal, they aren't.

Comment: @Tomalak Yes. I copied and pasted what the bot outputted and whenn I inputted it as you can see in the line after that the bot, it pinged me, which is impossible unless you have the exact string

Comment: Not copy and paste and visual inspection. write a loop that outputs to the console two rows of character codes of the two strings you assume to be equal.

Comment: @Tomalak I just did and there is no difference

Comment: You're comparing characters again. Compare character codes to be absolutely sure. I suspect whitespace differences.

Comment: Possibly related, maybe not though, Are you trying to compare a raw string discord tag to a mention? because mentions have the syntax `<@USER_ID>`, whereas discord tags are `USER_NAME#0000` which are vastly different...

Answer (score 0):

Discord's mentions are done via `<@User_ID>`, so instead of sending `@Person`, you need to send `<@1957217385902874>` or something to that effect.

You *can* get a member object by their name in D.py via `server.get_member_named('Person#0001')`, but that may not always work since people can change their names.